# SSIS Foreach loop container suggestions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have not used a foreach loop container before and need some help with this.

I have a SSIS package that at the moment does some stuff (import from excel into database, some merges, some joins).

Basically at the end I finish with a table that contains the following fields (modified):

```
Invoice number
Container number
Item number
Item price
item duty
(...)
```

I need it to do some specific SQL (joins, insert formulas ...) for each invoice and export that to an Excel file with file name = invoice number.

I thought of getting a `select distinct ROW_NUmber () (...),[Invoice_number] from [invoicetable]` and getting to iterate over the row_number basically and do what I needed it to do.

I've thought about maybe getting this on a SQL loop to create #temp1, #temp2, ... and then export all of the #temp individually and then dropping them.

I am looking for ideas of the most efficient way of getting this done.

I must say I have tried T-SQL to get the files to be exported using cmd but I keep getting errors trying to create the files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Foreach loop container seems reasonable. Set a variable = to the source connection for the Excel file. Use the variable as the invoice number in a data flow. Loop for each file in the folder.

Comment: @JacobH sorry but by reading your explanation it makes me think you thought I wanted to import the files and not export. Might have understood your explanation wrong but that's what I feel. I get setting the variable in the connection so that the file name is the invoice number.

Comment: My idea is something along the lines of:
@InvoiceResult=0
@i=0

InvoiceResult=InvoiceNumber where ROWNUM=(i)
set (i)=(i)+1

; filename variable [@invoiceresult].csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up giving up on the foreach loop container. As the data input to my tables was an excel file I had so many problems with data type conversions in the middle that nothing wanted to work in the loop. I couldn't get it to iterate over the invoice "number/name".

I ended up looking at C# as an option and managed to loop it but could not get it to loop inside the loop initially, after some trial an error I managed to get the outcome I needed and this process is now running what prior BA created with 4 macros, in SSIS package reducing work time from 1800 minutes to 3.

The C# code is here:

[C# Variable Excel file output loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593230/c-sharp-variable-excel-file-output-loop)

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is use an `Execute SQL Task` to populate an object variable with all the invoice numbers in your table.

Then have a `foreach loop` that iterates over that object variable and begins with a script task that uses the value of the invoice number to set the name of your destination excel file, and also to generate the SQL Command of your data flow's source component to SELECT from the table `WHERE InvoiceNumber={the current invoice number in the loop}`.

Each iteration of the loop will select one invoice and send it to one appropriately-named Excel file.   Then move on to the next invoice number.

Comment: ok so I've tried doing this. I set the variable named PO. I have a SQL task as follows: SELECT DISTINCT Purchase_order
FROM            Staging.InputWOrigin AS iw
WHERE        (Transfer_Reference = ' ')

ResultSet is set to "Full set Result" under the Result Set options I have Result Name 0 and variable Name User::PO. I tried having this task inside or outside the foreachloop but I get this error."The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::PO" differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution.

Comment: What is the data type of your `PO` variable?   It needs to be "Object".

Comment: Allerman, I've tried that and didn't work. I did it again now for my own sanity and it worked...let me try again the foreach loop tomorrow and I'll see if the rest is working as it should.