# C# Variable Excel file output loop

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I had opened a question about doing this on a SSIS package with the for loop but I kept getting errors (datatype conversion issues) so I decided to take a dab at C#.

I have this working code:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
#endregion

namespace ST_6704c764a25b4ffa92f62385be46f235
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");


            try
            {
                //Declare Variables
                string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString();
                string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
                string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
                string SheetName = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
                ExcelFileName = ExcelFileName + "_" + datetime;

                OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
                OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();

                //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
                string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FolderPath + ExcelFileName
                    + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

                //drop Excel file if exists
                File.Delete(FolderPath + "\\" + ExcelFileName + ".xlsx");

                //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
                SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);




                //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
                // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
                string queryString =
                  "SELECT Post_Advice, Purchase_order, Article from " + TableName;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);


                //Get Header Columns
                string TableColumns = "";

                // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    {
                        TableColumns += column + "],[";
                    }
                }

                // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
                TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
                TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);
                //MessageBox.Show(TableColumns);


                //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
                Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
                Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                    String sqlCommandValue = "";
                    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                    {
                        sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                    }

                    sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                    sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                    sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into " + SheetName + "(" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',') + ") VALUES(";

                    int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        string columnvalues = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                        {
                            int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                            columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";

                        }
                        columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                        var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                        Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                        Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
                Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                    Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                }
            }
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

What I am missing is that this will generate 1 file with all results from the query.

I want to run 2 queries, the first one creates the result of:

```
var post_adv int
    Select distinct Post_advice from TableName;
adapter.fill(post_adv)
```

I then want the above query to run with a loop having the query be something like:

```
select * from TableName where Post_advice=post_adv
```

It will also be necessary that the FileName be that Post_advice instead of the current variable.

I am just having some difficulties getting the second query to execute as well.

This is my first try using C# and I've spent some hours reading but I am fairly new to this :)

Thanks for all the help!

Edit:

Solution for this problem:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");



            //Declare Variables

            string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
            string SheetName = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();

            OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();



            //USE ADO.NET Connection for the loop initialisation
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection2 = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection2 = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
            //Load data into the loop table
            string queryString2 =
       "SELECT distinct PO from " + TableName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString2, myADONETConnection2);
            var table2 = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table2);
            var numberofrows = table2.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cell = table2.Rows[i]["PO"];

                    string ExcelFileName = (string)cell;
                    ExcelFileName = ExcelFileName + "_" + datetime;

                    //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
                    string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FolderPath + ExcelFileName
                        + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

                    //drop Excel file if exists
                    File.Delete(FolderPath + "\\" + ExcelFileName + ".xlsx");

                    //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table

                    SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                    myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


                    //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
                    // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
                    string queryString =
                      "SELECT * from " + TableName + "where PO=" + cell;
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter2.Fill(ds);


                    //Get Header Columns
                    string TableColumns = "";

                    // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            TableColumns += column + "],[";
                        }
                    }

                    // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
                    TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
                    TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);
                    //MessageBox.Show(TableColumns);


                    //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
                    Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
                    Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                        String sqlCommandValue = "";
                        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                        {
                            sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                        }

                        sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                        sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                        sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into " + SheetName + "(" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',') + ") VALUES(";

                        int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            string columnvalues = "";
                            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                            {
                                int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                                columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[j] + "',";

                            }
                            columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                            var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    }
                    Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                    myADONETConnection.Close();
                }


                catch (Exception exception)
                {

                    // Create Log File for Errors
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                        Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + ".log"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution for this myself :)

Comment: You can add an answer to this post, and accept your own answer. This helps other people who come across your question while searching for answers to their question(s).

Comment: Thanks digital.aaron I've done that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");



            //Declare Variables

            string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
            string SheetName = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();

            OleDbConnection Excel_OLE_Con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Excel_OLE_Cmd = new OleDbCommand();



            //USE ADO.NET Connection for the loop initialisation
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection2 = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection2 = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
            //Load data into the loop table
            string queryString2 =
       "SELECT distinct PO from " + TableName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString2, myADONETConnection2);
            var table2 = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table2);
            var numberofrows = table2.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cell = table2.Rows[i]["PO"];

                    string ExcelFileName = (string)cell;
                    ExcelFileName = ExcelFileName + "_" + datetime;

                    //Construct ConnectionString for Excel
                    string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FolderPath + ExcelFileName
                        + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";

                    //drop Excel file if exists
                    File.Delete(FolderPath + "\\" + ExcelFileName + ".xlsx");

                    //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table

                    SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
                    myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


                    //Load Data into DataTable from SQL ServerTable
                    // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
                    string queryString =
                      "SELECT * from " + TableName + "where PO=" + cell;
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, myADONETConnection);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter2.Fill(ds);


                    //Get Header Columns
                    string TableColumns = "";

                    // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            TableColumns += column + "],[";
                        }
                    }

                    // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
                    TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
                    TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);
                    //MessageBox.Show(TableColumns);


                    //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
                    Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
                    Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
                    Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    //Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                        String sqlCommandValue = "";
                        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                        {
                            sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                        }

                        sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                        sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                        sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into " + SheetName + "(" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',') + ") VALUES(";

                        int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            string columnvalues = "";
                            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                            {
                                int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                                columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[j] + "',";

                            }
                            columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                            var command = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = command;
                            Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    }
                    Excel_OLE_Con.Close();
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                    myADONETConnection.Close();
                }


                catch (Exception exception)
                {

                    // Create Log File for Errors
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                        Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + ".log"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow best practice, even when answering your own problem, is to provide a short explanation as to "why" your answer solves the problem in the question. You can also "Accept" your answer to show it's the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this solution.It really worked for me.
I only had to add these brackets `[` before and after sheet name as below part of create and insert query of the code:

```
Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table [" + SheetName + "]  (" + TableColumns + ")"; //SheetName should be in []

Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Write Data to Excel Sheet from DataTable dynamically
foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in Results.Tables)
{
    String sqlCommandInsert = "";
    String sqlCommandValue = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
    {
        sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
    }
    sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
    sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
    sqlCommandInsert = "INSERT into [" + SheetName + "] (" + sqlCommandValue + ") VALUES (";
```